# CSS3 transition scale but not translation

Tags: css, css-transitions

I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere, probably because it doesn't exist, but anyway:

Rather than defining "transition-property: transform", is it possible to define transitions for translation and scale independently?

Right now I got the following definition:

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-out;
}
```

This way, when I set "-webkit-transform" to "scale($s) translate3D($x,$y,$z)" (with $s etc. being arbitrary values) both are animated, but I only want the scale to be...

Thanks for any hints in advance!

Comment: `scale` and `translate` are the value of the same css properties I don't think its posible to seperate them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The hacky way to solve this is to use a wrapper element and put the translate on that element.

Comment: Thanks! I honestly didn't think of that possibility. :'-)