# how to flip and rotate an image using css in chrome

Tags: css

I tried to flip an image and then rotate it using css.

This is the page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title> Mounts </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            img {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
                -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src='1.jpg'>
    </body>
</html>
```

But one of the transform functions was disabled by chrome.

Is it illegal to use more than one transform function ?

Comment: If you want to have different delays for these see: [CSS3 transition scale but not translation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841340/css3-transition-scale-but-not-translation) (or use a keyframe animation) (using @MichaelPeterson's answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine them in one statement:

`transform: rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1);`

Or you could use the matrix property: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp

There's even generators for the code, such as: http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transform.html

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with Lea Verou's rotating sign too. It did not work without modification in webkit. This is how I solved it:

```
    <style>
    div {
  width: 9em;
  padding: .6em 1em;
  margin: 2em auto;
  background: yellowgreen;
  -webkit-animation-name: spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
    }
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

    div:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
</style>


    <div ontouchstart="">Hover over me and watch me spin!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem and I could solve it in this way:
(I just wanted to rotate and flap a photo with class of left-img)
(and enjoy;))

```
.left-img{
-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
```

}